# SQL statement for generating random data

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have this Oracle table which I want to populate with random data:

```
CREATE TABLE AGENT_HISTORY(
  EVENTID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  AGENTID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EVENT_DATE DATE,
  CPU INTEGER,
  RAM NUMBER,
  HDD NUMBER,
  NETWORK_UP NUMBER,
  NETWORK_DOWN NUMBER
)
/

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE AGENT_HISTORY

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP1 ON AGENT_HISTORY (AGENTID)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE AGENT_HISTORY

ALTER TABLE AGENT_HISTORY ADD CONSTRAINT KEY8 PRIMARY KEY (EVENTID)
/
```

How I can generate random data for 60 days back(column EVENT_DATE)? Every day I want to insert for example some random network traffic data?

Comment: You have to use dbms_random package to generate random numbers. and 60 days back means? and how many rows you have to generate??

Comment: I need 60 events(or more) for 60 days back.

Comment: Do you want to generate data for all column randomly??

Comment: Only for AGENTID I need to have always value 1.

Comment: provide table structer with constraints like unique key, primary key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below pl/sql block for generating random data and also it will insert into your table.

```
    declare 
      v_EVENTID INTEGER;
      v_AGENTID INTEGER:=1;
      v_EVENT_DATE  DATE:=sysdate-60; 
      v_CPU INTEGER;
      v_RAM NUMBER;
      v_HDD NUMBER;
      v_NETWORK_UP NUMBER;
      v_NETWORK_DOWN NUMBER;
    begin 
    for i in 1..100
    loop
    v_EVENT_DATE:=v_EVENT_DATE-1;
    select i,ceil(dbms_random.value(1,1000)),floor(dbms_random.value(1,1000)),ceil(dbms_random.value(1,100))*2,floor(dbms_random.value(1,100))*2,100+i
     into v_EVENTID,v_CPU,v_ram,v_HDD,v_NETWORK_UP,v_NETWORK_DOWN    from dual;
    --insert into AGENT_HISTORY values(v_EVENTID,v_AGENTID,v_EVENT_DATE,v_CPU,v_ram,v_HDD,v_NETWORK_UP,v_NETWORK_DOWN);
dbms_output.put_line(v_EVENTID||' '||v_AGENTID||' '||v_EVENT_DATE||' '||v_CPU||' '||v_ram||' '||v_HDD||' '||v_NETWORK_UP||' '||v_NETWORK_DOWN) ;
    end loop;
    end;
```

Comment: I updated the post. Column AGENTID is always with value 1

Comment: I get Error report -
ORA-06550: line 18, column 13:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 18, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Please check the latest pl/sql block i have updated it. I have missed ram column thats why we got error:)

Comment: I get Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (ADMIN.KEY8) violated
ORA-06512: at line 16
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.

Comment: Again i have edited the pl/sql block please check once.

Comment: I get Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (ADMIN.KEY8) violated
ORA-06512: at line 16
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.

Comment: any rows existed in a table previously.

Comment: Delete and execute pl/sql block. if you want to generate more no of rows then change i value in a loop from 100 to your required number.

Comment: I remove all data. I run your script and I get the same error. Random data is inserted into the table.

Comment: By the way maybe we need to add commit at the end?

Comment: By using Dbms_output package print the values return by a select query like dbms_output.put_line(v_EVENTID||'  '||v_AGENTID||'  '||v_EVENT_DATE||'  '||v_CPU||'  '||v_ram||'  '||v_HDD||'  '||v_NETWORK_UP||'  '||v_NETWORK_DOWN)   after that analyze the data then find the mistakes after that alter the pl/sql block. yes we have to add commit.

Comment: i have updated post please check and i have created your table in my schema and i ran pl/sql block it is working fine for me.

Comment: I get ORA-06550: line 18, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( % ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Just add semicolon to the end of Dbms_output statement.

Comment: Yes! I get PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Comment: How I can delete all columns data with one SQL query?

Comment: use truncate table AGENT_HISTORY .

Comment: One small question. Looks like after I run the script I need to commit it. Where I have to put commit?

Comment: In your editor write commit and select that then press F5.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO AGENT_HISTORY (EVENTID, AGENTID, EVENT_DATE, CPU, RAM, HDD, NETWORK_UP, NETWORK_DOWN)
SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL, TRUNC(SYSDATE - LEVEL + 1), DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE * 100, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a procedural-generation feel to your code, without actually context-switching over to PL/SQL, you could generate data using the [MODEL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/sqlmodel.htm) clause...

```
INSERT INTO agent_history (EVENTID, AGENTID, EVENT_DATE, CPU, RAM, HDD, NETWORK_UP, NETWORK_DOWN)
SELECT EVENTID, AGENTID, EVENT_DATE, CPU, RAM, HDD, NETWORK_UP, NETWORK_DOWN
FROM agent_history
MODEL DIMENSION BY (0 ITERATION)
      MEASURES (EVENTID, AGENTID, EVENT_DATE, CPU, RAM, HDD, NETWORK_UP, NETWORK_DOWN)
      RULES ITERATE (60) ( --Or however many days you want to iterate over
        EVENTID[ITERATION_NUMBER]      = 100-ITERATION_NUMBER,              
        AGENTID[ITERATION_NUMBER]      = 1,                                 
        EVENT_DATE[ITERATION_NUMBER]   = TRUNC(SYSDATE-ITERATION_NUMBER+1), 
        CPU[ITERATION_NUMBER]          = ceil(dbms_random.value(1,100)),
        RAM[ITERATION_NUMBER]          = floor(dbms_random.value(1,100)),
        HDD[ITERATION_NUMBER]          = ceil(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE * 100),
        NETWORK_UP[ITERATION_NUMBER]   = DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE * 100+1,
        NETWORK_DOWN[ITERATION_NUMBER] = DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE * ITERATION_NUMBER
      )
ORDER BY EVENT_DATE;
```